# How to compile linux kernel 0.12 and debug it with bochs and gdb?

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, bochs

I have download linux 0.12 source code and bochs souce code.I compiled linux 0.12 souce code in linux-0.12 .Then I compiled bochs with gdb-stub and installed in debian 6.0.
However, when I debug linux-0.12 kernel with gdb and bochs, it said in bochs:"Panic: HD Controller not ready".
Then how to debug it correctly?

Comment: I am also looking for the same answer. Were you able to do so succesfully ?